# What is needed in the HttpContext to allow FormsAuthentication.SignOut() to execute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write a unit test for our log out method. Among other things it  `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`. However, it throws a `System.NullReferenceException`.

I've created a mock; `HttpContext` (using Moq), but it is obviously missing something.

My mock context contains:

- A mocked `HttpRequestBase` on `Request`
- A mocked `HttpResponseBase` on `Response`
- With a `HttpCookieCollection` on `Request.Cookies` and another on `Response.Cookies`
- A mocked `IPrincipal` on `User`

*I am aware I could go the wrapper route and inject an empty `FormsAuth` wrapper object in it's place, but I would really like to avoid the 3 additional files just to fix one line of code. That and I am still curious for an answer*

So my question is "**What is needed in the `HttpContext` to allow `FormsAuthentication.SignOut() to execute.`**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the code for signout.

```
public static void SignOut()
{
    Initialize();
    HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
    bool flag = current.CookielessHelper.DoesCookieValueExistInOriginal('F');
    current.CookielessHelper.SetCookieValue('F', null);
    if (!CookielessHelperClass.UseCookieless(current, false, CookieMode) || current.Request.Browser.Cookies)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        if (current.Request.Browser["supportsEmptyStringInCookieValue"] == "false")
        {
            str = "NoCookie";
        }
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsCookieName, str);
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cookie.Path = _FormsCookiePath;
        cookie.Expires = new DateTime(0x7cf, 10, 12);
        cookie.Secure = _RequireSSL;
        if (_CookieDomain != null)
        {
            cookie.Domain = _CookieDomain;
        }
        current.Response.Cookies.RemoveCookie(FormsCookieName);
        current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        current.Response.Redirect(GetLoginPage(null), false);
    }
}
```

Looks like you need a CookielessHelperClass instance.  Too bad it's internal and sealed - there's no way to mock it unless you're using TypeMock.  +1 for wrapper suggestions :)

Comment: Perfect, exactly the answer I was after. Cheers :)

Comment: it`s like not an answer ... I need to mock FormsAuthentication and it doesn`t help me.

Comment: @Yaroslav Yakovlev - just because something doesn't help you, you shouldn't downvote it.  It obviously helped the original poster.

Comment: @Yaroslav Yakovlev You cannot mock FormsAuthentication unfortunatly since it is a static class. Which is why womp was talking about mocking the internals (and problems caused there)

Answer (score 20):

The NullReferenceException in this case is actually being thrown by the call:

```
current.Request.Browser["supportsEmptyStringInCookieValue"]
```

You can test this assertion by calling:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.SupportsEmptyStringInCookieValue
```

...which will also return the NullReferenceException. Contrary to the accepted answer, if you attempt to call:

```
CookielessHelperClass.UseCookieless(current, false, CookieMode)
```

...from the immediate window, this will return without error.

You can fix the exception like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities() { Capabilities = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "supportsEmptyStringInCookieValue", "false" } } };
```

...and the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` call will now succeed.

Comment: Great answer, it helps me a lot. Unfortunately I've got another exception (ArgumentNullException), but it is also possible to fix it with adding one more browser capability - "cookies". So the final answer is the next: HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities
            {
                Capabilities = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "supportsEmptyStringInCookieValue", "false" },
                    { "cookies", "false" },
                }
            };

Answer (score 13):

You can always wrap FormsAuthentication.SignOut() into another method and stub / mock it.

Create IFormsAuthenticationWrap interface.

```
public interface IFormsAuthenticationWrap
{
    void SignOut();
}
```

Create wrap class that implements IFormsAuthenticationWrap

```
public class FormsAuthenticationWrap : IFormsAuthenticationWrap
{
    public void SignOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
}
```

Your calling class is going to look something like this:

```
public class LogOutClass
{
    private readonly IFormsAuthenticationWrap _formsAuthentication;

    public LogOutClass() : this (new FormsAuthenticationWrap())
    {
    }

    public LogOutClass(IFormsAuthenticationWrap formsAuthentication)
    {
        _formsAuthentication = formsAuthentication;
    }

    public void LogOutMethod()
    {
        // Code before SignOut

        _formsAuthentication.SignOut();

        // Code after SignOut
    }
}
```

Now let's get to our test. You can stub / mock with Moq but I'm going to show here how you can do it manually. 
Create your stub / mock class:

```
public class FormsAuthenticationStub : IFormsAuthenticationWrap
{
    public void SignOut()
    {
    }
}
```

And the last write the test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLogOutMethod()
    {
        var logOutClass = new LogOutClass(new FormsAuthenticationStub());
        logOutClass.LogOutMethod();
    }
```

Comment: You can follow example I showed you in modified answer how you can break your external dependencies.

Comment: +1 as I mentioned in my answer, the wrapper is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

**The wrapper is the clean way to go.**

You mentioned in a comment that "this is going to be quite a big application", that's another argument to use the wrapper not the opposite. In a big application you want to have clear dependencies, and you want tests to be done easily.

You are trading clean dependencies that can be easily injected over obscure dependencies to the internal workings of asp.net in your tests.

---

On a different note: **Use Reflector**. I honestly don't know the inner dependencies of this specific part of asp.net, but you can clear any doubts with reflector.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've removed my comments suggesting about the "big application" as I have re-worded my question since. Obviously, regardless of application size, creating a wrapper and using dependency injection for such classes/methods is *the* way to go. (And will be the way I got if I want this unit test to pass)

I would however, still like to leave my question as it is.

Cheers for the tip on the Reflector, I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mock HttpContext, use a real one in your tests. This way you don't have to mock all these Http* stuff. You can use [Ivonna](http://ivonna.biz) and test your method directly, without mocking all these dependencies and getting mysterious exceptions.